# Не найден скрипт

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ошибка в консоли:

> scripts.js ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Указал его путь

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

На самом деле Путь выглядит так:

```
C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\stameska.ru\src\js\scripts.js
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать так: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: пишет Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Покажите адрес html файла

Comment: C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\stameska.ru\src\index.html

Comment: Странно, должно работать с адресом *"js/scripts.js"*. Точно адрес правильный?

Comment: может посоветуем ТС поднять фронтентд?

Comment: @norbornen, вроде уже?

Comment: @Qwertiy ага. видимо, когда я загрузил страницу твоего ответа ещё не было

Answer (score 3):

Выбирай:

1. Запустить реальный http-сервер. Тогда абсолютный путь будет считаться относительно него, а не относительно корня диска. При наличии nodejs можно так:

   ```
   npm i -g http-server
   http-server -p 3000 src
   ```
2. Использовать относительный путь к скрипту:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: не помогло.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не будет работать..